# Is there a connection limitation using LWIP？

Tags: sockets, tcp, lwip

I'm writing a TCP server using Lwip Protocol, normally the server can connect to multiple TCP clients. However I have a problem , the server can't connect more than three active connections. The 4th or more clients could not connect for unknown reasons. I looked around the forums and tried increasing the number limit for `MEMP_NUM_TCP_PCB` in opt.h (lwip-x86_64\include\lwip\opt.h) but it didn't help.

Following is my code, and my questions is whether is there a max connection limitation using LWIP ? Maximum number of connections is 3 or more?

```c
//server code 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#define MYPORT 1234    // the port users will be connecting to
#define BACKLOG 2// how many pending connections queue will hold
#define BUF_SIZE 1024
int fd_A[BACKLOG];    // accepted connection fd
int conn_amount;      // current connection amount
void showclient()
{
    int i;
    printf("-----> client amount: %d\n", conn_amount);
    for (i = 0; i < BACKLOG; i++) {
    printf("BACKLOG%d ---> fd = %d\n", i, fd_A[i]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");
}
int main(void)
{
    sleep(1);
    printf("start server\n");
    int sock_fd, new_fd;             // listen on sock_fd, new connection on new_fd
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr;  // server address information
    struct sockaddr_in client_addr;  // connector's address information
    socklen_t sin_size;
    int yes = 1;
    char buf[BUF_SIZE];
    int ret;
    int i;
    if ((sock_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
    perror("socket");
    exit(1);
    }
    //if (setsockopt(sock_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof(int)) == -1) {
    /*if (setsockopt(sock_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof(int)) == -1) {
    //perror("setsockopt");
    //exit(1);
    }
    if (fcntl(sock_fd, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK) == -1) {
    printf("Set server socket nonblock failed\n");
    exit(1);
    }*/
    memset(&server_addr, 0, sizeof(server_addr));
    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;         // host byte order
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(MYPORT);     // short, network byte order
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY); // automatically fill with my IP
    //memset(server_addr.sin_zero, '0', sizeof(server_addr.sin_zero));
    if (bind(sock_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) == -1) {
    perror("bind");
    exit(1);
    }
    printf("listen...\n");
    if (listen(sock_fd, BACKLOG) == -1) {
    perror("listen");
    exit(1);
    }
    printf("listen port %d\n", MYPORT);
    fd_set fdsr, wfds, efds;
    int maxsock;
    struct timeval tv;
    conn_amount = 0;
    sin_size = sizeof(client_addr);
    maxsock = sock_fd;
    while (1) 
    {
    sleep(1);  // it's necessary
    // initialize file descriptor set
    FD_ZERO(&fdsr);
    FD_ZERO(&wfds);
    //FD_ZERO(&efds);
    FD_SET(sock_fd, &fdsr);  // add fd
    FD_SET(sock_fd, &wfds);  // add fd
    //FD_SET(sock_fd, &efds);  // add fd
    // timeout setting
    tv.tv_sec = 30;
    tv.tv_usec = 0;
    // add active connection to fd set
    for (i = 0; i < BACKLOG; i++) {
        if (fd_A[i] != 0) {
            FD_SET(fd_A[i], &fdsr);
        }
    }
    //printf("before select!!!!!!!!!!!! ret = %d\n", ret);
    if ((select(maxsock + 1, &fdsr, &wfds, (fd_set*) 0, (struct timeval*) 0)) < 0) {
        perror("select");
        break;
    } 

    // check every fd in the set
    for (i = 0; i < conn_amount; i++) 
    {
        if (FD_ISSET(fd_A[i], &fdsr)) // check which fd is ready
        {
            ret = recv(fd_A[i], buf, sizeof(buf), 0);
            if (ret <= 0) 
            {        // client close
                printf("ret : %d and client[%d] close\n", ret, i);
                close(fd_A[i]);
                FD_CLR(fd_A[i], &fdsr);  // delete fd 
                fd_A[i] = 0;
                conn_amount--;
            }
            else 
            {        // receive data
                if (ret < BUF_SIZE)
                    memset(&buf[ret], '\0', 1); // add NULL('/0')
                printf("client[%d] send:%s\n", i, buf);
            }
        }
    }
    // check whether a new connection comes
    if (FD_ISSET(sock_fd, &fdsr))  // accept new connection 
    {
        new_fd = accept(sock_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, &sin_size);
        if (new_fd <= 0) 
        {
            perror("accept");
            continue;
        }
        // add to fd queue
        if (conn_amount < BACKLOG) 
        {
            fd_A[conn_amount++] = new_fd;
            printf("------> new connection client[%d] %s:%d\n", conn_amount,
                    inet_ntoa(client_addr.sin_addr), ntohs(client_addr.sin_port));
            if (new_fd > maxsock)  // update the maxsock fd for select function
                maxsock = new_fd;
        }
        else 
        {
            printf("max connections arrive, exit\n");
            send(new_fd, "bye", 4, 0);
            close(new_fd);
            break;   
        }
    }
    //showclient();
    }
    // close other connections
    for (i = 0; i < BACKLOG; i++) 
    {
    if (fd_A[i] != 0) 
    {
        close(fd_A[i]);
    }
    }
    exit(0);
}

//client code
#include   <sys/stat.h>   
#include   <sys/types.h>   
#include   <sys/socket.h>   
#include   <stdio.h>   
#include   <malloc.h>   
#include   <netdb.h>   
#include   <fcntl.h>
#include   <unistd.h>
#include   <netinet/in.h>
#include   <arpa/inet.h>
#include   <string.h>
#define    RES_LENGTH  10240 
int     connect_socket(char * server,int serverPort);
int     send_msg(int sockfd,char * sendBuff);
char *  recv_msg(int sockfd);
int     close_socket(int sockfd);
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    int   sockfd[1024] = {0};
    char  sendMsg[30]="zhangchengfei\r\n\r";
    char* res;
    int   port = 1234;
    char  ip[128] = {0};
    strncpy(ip, "10.107.19.62", 128);
    if(argc > 2)
    {
    strncpy(ip, argv[1], 128);
    port = atoi(argv[2]);
    printf("Input IP: %s, port : %d\n", ip, port);
    }
    else if(argc > 1)
    {   
    //port = atoi(argv[1]);
    //printf("Input port : %d\n", port);
    //
    int num_client = atoi(argv[1]);
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i <= num_client; i++) {
    printf("start connect %d\n", i + 1);           
    sockfd[i]=connect_socket(ip, port);
    printf("connect %d OK\n", i + 1);   
    getchar();
    }
    for (i = 0; i <= num_client; i++) {
    send_msg(sockfd[i], sendMsg);
    /* res=recv_msg(sockfd); */

    printf("client %d send msg = %s\n", i + 1, sendMsg);
    //printf(res);
    //free(res);
    getchar();
    }
    for (i = 0; i <= num_client; i++) {
    close_socket(sockfd[i]);
    printf("close socket %d\n", i + 1);
    }
    }
    return 0;
}

int    connect_socket(char * server,int serverPort){
    int    sockfd=0;
    struct    sockaddr_in    addr;
    struct    hostent        * phost;

    if((sockfd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0))<0){
    herror("Init socket error!");
    return -1;
    }
    bzero(&addr,sizeof(addr));
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(serverPort);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(server);

    if(addr.sin_addr.s_addr == INADDR_NONE){
    phost = (struct hostent*)gethostbyname(server);
    if(phost==NULL){
        herror("Init socket s_addr error!");
        return -1;
    }
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr =((struct in_addr*)phost->h_addr)->s_addr;
    }
    if(connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr))<0)
    {
    perror("Connect server fail!");
    return -1; 
    }
    else
    return sockfd;
}


int send_msg(int sockfd,char * sendBuff)
{
    int sendSize=0;
    if((sendSize=send(sockfd,sendBuff,strlen(sendBuff),0))<=0){
    herror("Send msg error!");
    return -1;
    }else
    return sendSize;
}


char* recv_msg(int sockfd){
    char * response;
    int  flag=0,recLenth=0;
    response=(char *)malloc(RES_LENGTH);
    memset(response,0,RES_LENGTH);

    for(flag=0;;)
    {
    printf("======recv data:\n");
    if(( recLenth=recv(sockfd,response+flag,RES_LENGTH-flag,0))==-1 )
    {
        free(response);
        printf("Return value : %d\n", recLenth);
        perror("Recv msg error : ");
        return NULL;
    }
    else if(recLenth==0)
        break;
    else
    {
        printf("%d char recieved data : %s.\n", recLenth, response+flag);
        flag+=recLenth;
        recLenth=0;
    }
    }
    printf("Return value : %d\n", recLenth);
    response[flag]='0';
    return response;
}


int close_socket(int sockfd)
{
    close(sockfd);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When you say "the server can't connect more than three active connections" can you update the description to be more specific?  Which socket API calls is failing?  accept()?  If so, please capture the error code via errno or getsockopt( ..., SO_ERROR); and update the description

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem caused by a `Makefile` bug in `./stubdom`, after executing `make crossclean` , I found the `.o` files still existed in `lwip-x86_64` folder. So I add a command `find . -name "*.o" | xargs rm -f` in Makefile and then anything is OK.

The reason is that lwip configure is given by the macro definition, macro definition have been replaced at the pre-compilation stage, so if I modify the lwip configure and did not delete the `.o` files, there is no effect. Following is the macro definitions I have modified in `opt.h`.

```
    MEMP_NUM_TCP_PCB 100
    MEMP_NUM_TCP_PCB_LISTEN 100
    MEMP_NUM_NETCONN 100
```

Now the server can break through the connection limitations and more than 3 active TCP connections can be established.